# Java class file JDK version

Tags: java, compilation, .class-file

I need to add more logs to several classes of specific java module (module is compiled, no sources available). I have successfully extracted sources, but i am  confused on which JDK version is to be used to re-compile modified classes.

```
javap -verbose className.class
```

shows

```
...
major version: 46
...
```

Doesn't `46 version` mean that initially class were compiled with **JDK 1.2** 
But source file contains imports from java nio:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
```

which was implemented in the **java 5**
The question is: **How its can be?**

Notes:
*+ the whole systems running under open-jdk 1.5*
*+ date of creation module ~2006 year*

Answer (score 1):

The compiler generates class files compatible withh older versions when you use the -target command line switch.

The files you have were probably compiled with `-source 1.2 target 1.2`. The compatibility only affects what bytecode instructions are used, it doesn't stop you from using newer APIs.

Comment: Joni, so actualy itl means that sources where compiled for e.x. under JDK 1.5 and set compatibility level for 1.2?